# Android auto take picture

Tags: java, android, camera

I am working on app that is suppose to take a selfie every 20 minutes without the user interface or user pressing something. I start this job using a `JobScheduler` and I create a notification that tells the user that my app is working. I've managed to take a slefie but it needs user's action and preview and I do not want this. I just simply want to take a selfie without the preview or user pressing a button.

```
private void pic()
{
    Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camera,7);
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        Log.d("bine","true");
        if (requestCode == 7)
        {
            Log.d("bine","true");
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            img.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
```

P.S: I am working with android 9!

Comment: http://cell0907.blogspot.com/2014/01/android-camera-capture-without.html or here http://chandandroid.blogspot.com/2014/04/capturing-image-without-user-action.html

Comment: @Kirguduck is it working for android 9?